# Creating and saving a text file to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net

In C# ASP.Net, I would like to create and save a text file to a server.  This will be happening daily (by a user action, not scheduled).

I would like the location to not be in the application path but in a separate folder (for this question, lets say the folder is off the root).

I am new to this site and if this question is too "open", feel free to let me know.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with [Dan Herbert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/922464/4251431). Put the path in web.config and make sure the permissions for the folder are correct.

Also, make sure that path is not on the C drive. That way, if something goes wrong, or if the site is attacked, the c drive won't fill up and crash the server.

Be careful with the permissions; even a simple text file can be dangerous if a hacker can muck with the path somehow. Think about someone overwriting the server's hosts file, for example.

Answer (score 3):

One good practice to follow is to use a `web.config` app setting key to define the output path of your application.

You'd use the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` class for retrieving values from a `web.config`. You can read how to do this here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
// Pass a path and filename to the StreamWriter's
// constructor.  The path must already exist but the
// file will be created if it does not already exist.
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("c:\\foo\\bar.txt"))
{
    tw.WriteLine("hello world");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use System.IO classes to save to a file on the local filesystem.

```
using(var w = new StreamWriter(filename))
{
    w.WriteLine("Hello world!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add on what others have said, when writing to a file in a multi-threaded application, you need to synchronize the access to this resource. You could use [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) to achieve this:

```
// Make this a static field
ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

_lock.EnterWriteLock();
try
{
    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\test.txt", "some info to write");
}
finally
{
    _lock.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any specific issue in doing so. You just need to make sure the user running ASP.NET is granted the required permissions to write to the output folder.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use Server.MapPath to get to the physical path of your folder.

```
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("Folder1")))
    {
        tw.WriteLine("hello world"); 
    }
```